# Como Instalar Pascal en Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, pascal

¿Que IDE puedo utilizar para programar en pascal con Ubuntu?
¿Que comandos utilizo para instalarlo, o instalador? 
Tengo la versión 17.10.
Y, si se puede, me pueden también indicar un manual o libro para aprenderlo.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El compilador de Pascal gratuito se incluye en el repositorio de Ubuntu como  paquete fp-compiler . Por lo tanto, para instalar el compilador, debe instalar el compilador fp , ejecutando este comando en un terminal.

```
$ sudo apt-get install fp-compiler
```

Escriba su contraseña de root y espere hasta que finalice la instalación. Ahora puede compilar archivos de código fuente de Pascal ( .pas ), por ejemplo, ejecutando

```
$ fpc file.pas
```

para compilar un código fuente llamado file.pas en el directorio actual.

Puede crear archivos Pascal en cualquier editor de texto. Sin embargo, si prefiere desarrollar con Free Pascal IDE ( entorno de desarrollo integrado ), puede instalar el  paquete fp-ide .

```
$ sudo apt-get install fp-ide
```

Para iniciar el IDE, ejecuta

```
$ fp
```

Tu terminal se convertirá en el legendario editor azul de Free Pascal. Puede recibir una advertencia de error Debian dependiendo de su versión de Ubuntu, pero simplemente puede ignorarla.

Fuente : http://fusharblog.com/installing-free-pascal-in-ubuntu/